# How to get a specific word in a line from a text file

Tags: c#, file

I'm trying to make an `if` statement if the line contains "MATERIAL" then do something.
But "Material" is not founded in the text document.

**Code Snippet:**

```
 _testFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);

 foreach (var testFiles in _testFiles )
 {
     foreach (string lineArgument in System.IO.File.ReadLines(testFiles ))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("-- {0}", lineArgument);
         if (lineArgument.Contains("MATERIAL"))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Wie geht es euch");
         }
     }
 }
```

**Text File**

```
                     MATERIAL            ...................*mat
```

I did try to find a solution in google but didn't find one for my case.

Comment: In what way do you think it's not working? As far as I can see, the program will pause after the first line of the file until you press any key - is it just that you're not making the program progress by pressing a button for every line?

Comment: Forgot to delete it, was for testing purpose

Comment: the code is running without stopping. it dont stop at MATERIAL to print Console.Write...

Comment: Did you try [Contains(String, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0#system-string-contains(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` ? => See https://dotnetfiddle.net/vbJk0w

Comment: ^^ containing different versions of Upper/Lowercase : https://dotnetfiddle.net/IPdb4g

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
_testFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);

 foreach (var testFiles in _testFiles )
 {
     foreach (string lineArgument in System.IO.File.ReadLines(testFiles ))
     {
         lineArgument = lineArgument.Trim();
         Console.WriteLine("-- {0}", lineArgument);
         if (lineArgument.StartsWith("MATERIAL"))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Wie geht es euch");
         }
     }
 }
```

this will trim the spaces before and after and see if the line starts with the word `MATERIAL`.